What alternative can I use for camview for my android studio project
compile ('eu.livotov.labs.android:CAMView:2.0.1@aar') {transitive=true}
I use this library android studio says it cannot find the class probably it is retired what option can I use to replace this or is there a solution for the above lub an using android studio kaola. It is meant to scan live data with reference to firebase database
Thank you
I tried it on XML using the EU.livoto...
Android studio could not find the class.
I even tried to add it manually into the android studio still couldn't fix it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

<eu.livotov.labs.android.camview.ScannerLiveView //i get an error in this line that the library is retired and cannot be found
android:id="@+id/camview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp"
/>

